# Spatial data are in PostGIS but wanting to display labels from MapServer web service?

Tags: postgis, mapserver

My database of spatial data wkb is in PostGIS and my textual data is in sqlserver now is it possible to show labels through a MapServer web service?

I have common id in both the databases through which I can join textual data and spatial data.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be if you could copy the data from your sqlserver into your PostGres database. If that is not possible, I see two other options, which are more complicated:

Either you merge the data on the backend, such that MapServer can render the map based on the imported textual information. If I understood right, you would need to perform a cross-database query in SQL. In PostGIS/PostGres you can do that using [Foregin Data Wrappers](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#SQL_Database_Wrappers). If you are able to set this up as a query in PostGres, then you can probably get the data passed to Mapserver by using a custom query for it, here are some [examples from the Documentation](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html#data-access-connection-method).

The other option is that you combine the data on the front end. One way to do that could be by using the Mapserver [Web Feature Service Capability](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/wfs.html) for the map, and query the second database through an API or something, such that you combine the data using javascript on the front-end.